# Opening Up Port in Cherrypy Configuration

Tags: python, cherrypy

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cherrypy

cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': "10.0.1.15",'server.socket_port': 80})

class HelloWorld(object):
    def index(self):
        return "HelloWorld"
    index.exposed = True

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

That's my code but I get

```
[29/Jan/2014:11:16:14] ENGINE Bus STOPPING
[29/Jan/2014:11:16:14] ENGINE HTTP Server             
cherrypy._cpwsgi_server.CPWSGIServer(('10.0.1.15', 80)) already shut down
[29/Jan/2014:11:16:14] ENGINE Stopped thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
[29/Jan/2014:11:16:14] ENGINE Stopped thread 'Autoreloader'.
[29/Jan/2014:11:16:14] ENGINE Bus STOPPED
[29/Jan/2014:11:16:14] ENGINE Bus EXITING
[29/Jan/2014:11:16:14] ENGINE Bus EXITED
```

I have DHCP reservation for internal address 10.0.1.15 and I have opened up port 80 for the address as well on my airport extreme setup.

Comment: run a root@yoursystem # ps -ef|grep python. Look and see if your app is still running from a previous startup.

Comment: the app wasn't still running but i tried running the server as root this time and it worked. i have rwx permissions as normal user so i'm assuming that changing host/port configurations through cherrypy requires root access for some reason.

Comment: well at least you're on track. I use uwsgi and it seems the user it runs as need to be the owner of the files it accesses - that or chmod -R 744.

Comment: Ports below 1024 are privileged, so you must be root to bind

Comment: thank you both for your answers\